# Getting No such file or directory: 'ganache-cli' error

Tags: npm, path, ethereum, ganache, brownie

I installed ganache-cli using `npm install -g ganache-cli`, however I am running into a `No such file or directory: 'ganache-cli` error when trying to run it. When calling `echo $PATH`, I see `~/.npm-global/bin`, which contains the ganache-cli file, so I am confused as to what the issue could be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

For reference, I am using zsh on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

ganache-cli is now deprecated. You might see the following npm-warning:

```
npm WARN deprecated ganache-cli@6.12.2: ganache-cli is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
```

Use `npm install -g ganache`.

Use `sudo npm install -g ganache` if you get some error like this:

```
$ npm install -g ganache
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2022-06-23T12_37_16_476Z-debug.log
```